# how to get bazel shell command example to work?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to get shell commands to work with bazel (v4.2.1).  I am using this [page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/main/rules/shell_command) from the bazelbuild github as a reference.  The example uses a combination of a `BUILD` file and a `rules.bzl` file. The `rules.bzl` file is included in the `BUILD` file. For simplicity I am using a single file `foo/shell_command/BUILD`.

This is the contents of my BUILD file:

```
"""Rules that execute shell commands to do simple transformations.
While shell commands are convenient, they should be used carefully. Shell
commands are subject to escaping and injection issues, as well as portability
problems. It is often better to declare a binary target in a BUILD file and
execute it.
For very simple commands that are only used for a small number of targets, it
may be simpler to use genrule()s in a BUILD file instead of a custom rule that
invokes shell commands.
"""


def _emit_size_impl(ctx):
    # The input file is given to us from the BUILD file via an attribute.
    in_file = ctx.file.file

    # The output file is declared with a name based on the target's name.
    out_file = ctx.actions.declare_file("%s.size" % ctx.attr.name)

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        # Input files visible to the action.
        inputs = [in_file],
        # Output files that must be created by the action.
        outputs = [out_file],
        # The progress message uses `short_path` (the workspace-relative path)
        # since that's most meaningful to the user. It omits details from the
        # full path that would help distinguish whether the file is a source
        # file or generated, and (if generated) what configuration it is built
        # for.
        progress_message = "Getting size of %s" % in_file.short_path,
        # The command to run. Alternatively we could use '$1', '$2', etc., and
        # pass the values for their expansion to `run_shell`'s `arguments`
        # param (see convert_to_uppercase below). This would be more robust
        # against escaping issues. Note that actions require the full `path`,
        # not the ambiguous truncated `short_path`.
        command = "wc -c '%s' | awk '{print $1}' > '%s'" %
                  (in_file.path, out_file.path),
    )

    # Tell Bazel that the files to build for this target includes
    # `out_file`.
    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([out_file]))]



# this loaded
emit_size = rule(
    implementation = _emit_size_impl,
    attrs = {
        "file": attr.label(
            mandatory = True,
            allow_single_file = True,
            doc = "The file whose size is computed",
        ),
    },
    doc = """
Given an input file, creates an output file with the extension `.size`
containing the file's size in bytes.
""",
)

def _convert_to_uppercase_impl(ctx):
    # Both the input and output files are specified by the BUILD file.
    in_file = ctx.file.input
    out_file = ctx.outputs.output
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [out_file],
        inputs = [in_file],
        arguments = [in_file.path, out_file.path],
        command = "tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < \"$1\" > \"$2\"",
    )
    # No need to return anything telling Bazel to build `out_file` when
    # building this target -- It's implied because the output is declared
    # as an attribute rather than with `declare_file()`.


# this loaded
convert_to_uppercase = rule(
    implementation = _convert_to_uppercase_impl,
    attrs = {
        "input": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            mandatory = True,
            doc = "The file to transform",
        ),
        "output": attr.output(doc = "The generated file"),
    },
    doc = "Transforms a text file by changing its characters to uppercase.",
)



emit_size(
    name = "foo",
    file = "foo.txt",
)


convert_to_uppercase(
    name = "make_uppercase",
    input = "foo.txt",
    output = "upper_foo.txt",
)
```

My file system is setup like so:

```
~/xxx/mysrc 
$ tree .
.
├── shell_command
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── BUILD_ORIG
│   └── foo.txt
└── WORKSPACE
```

When I try to build the example with Bazel, I get the following result:

```
$ bazel build //shell_command
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:42:13: name 'DefaultInfo' is not defined
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:47:13: name 'rule' is not defined
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:50:17: name 'attr' is not defined
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:78:24: name 'rule' is not defined
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:81:18: name 'attr' is not defined
ERROR: /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD:86:19: name 'attr' is not defined
ERROR: Skipping '//shell_command': no such target '//shell_command:shell_command': target 'shell_command' not declared in package 'shell_command' defined by /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such target '//shell_command:shell_command': target 'shell_command' not declared in package 'shell_command' defined by /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/mysrc/shell_command/BUILD
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.771s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded)
```

FWIW, I have tried various directories and command variants to get the build to work, but they all give the same result:

Here in the directory with the `WORKSPACE` file.

```
~/xxx/xxx/mysrc 
$ ls -FC
shell_command/  WORKSPACE
~/xxx/xxx/mysrc 
$ bazel build //shell_command
```

Likewise, specifying the directory(?) and target(?):

```
$ bazel build //shell_command:shell_command
```

Comment: FWIW, regarding the error for DefaultInfo, that is a built-in and included in bazel 4.2.1 https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.2.1/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't merge `rules.bzl` and your `BUILD` file. Bazel does not support calling `rule` (and various other methods) in a `BUILD` file. You must load a bzl file with these definitions, as the bazelbuild github example does.

Comment: Ahh, very good. I figured it was just an elaboration.  LOL, its still failing, but I'm working on it.  Perhaps because I have this source inside another filesystem built with bazel that is the problem.  I'll update the question when its working.  Thanks a bunch @Christopher Parsons.

Comment: Indeed.  This works.  I also had to modify my build method.  Summary, I split the files and then issued the correct build command. `bazel build //shell_command:*`  This command can be done in the `WORKSPACE` directory or the subdir `shell_command`.